# PHP OAuth class not found. PHP 7 AOuth part of Core?

Tags: php, oauth

I'm using a shared WordPress server. I asked them to install the PHP OAuth 2.0 extension, and they replied and said that, as of PHP 7, this is part of its core.

Yet, for some reason when I try my code to connect to beatport.com's AOuth, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'OAuth' not found in
>   /var/sites/t/trancemusicevents.com/public_html/beatportapi/beatport_api.php:80
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /var/sites/t/trancemusicevents.com/public_html/beatportapi/beatport_api.php
>   on line 80

Here's the code that it refers to:

```
<?php
/**
 * Beatport OAuth API by Federico Giust
 * Based on Beatport OAuth Connect by Tim Brandwijk
 *
 * Needs beatport_callback.php script to verify the credentials:
 *  <?php
 *       $credentials = array();
 *       foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
 *           $credentials[$key] = $value;
 *       }
 *       if (!empty($credentials)) print json_encode($credentials);
 *   ?>
 */

/**
* Include config file where we store the corresponding constants.
*/
include 'config.php';

/**
* Include to log the api calls in the db.
*/
include('log_calls.php');

// Set default timezone to beatport timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

// Beatport URLs. Note the oauth_callback after the request url. This is needed to catch the verifier string:
$req_url = 'https://oauth-api.beatport.com/identity/1/oauth/request-token?oauth_callback='.urlencode(WEBSITE);
$authurl = 'https://oauth-api.beatport.com/identity/1/oauth/authorize';
$auth_submiturl = "https://oauth-api.beatport.com/identity/1/oauth/authorize-submit";
$acc_url = 'https://oauth-api.beatport.com/identity/1/oauth/access-token';

$conskey = CONSUMERKEY; // Beatport Consumer Key
$conssec = SECRETKEY; // Beatport Consumer Secret
$beatport_login = BEATPORTLOGIN; // Beatport Username
$beatport_password = BEATPORTPASSWORD; // Beatport Password

// URL Parameters to make the api call and generate a JSON object
if(isset($_GET['facets'])) {
    $facets=$_GET['facets'];
}
if(isset($_GET['sortBy'])){
    $sortBy=$_GET['sortBy'];
}
if(isset($_GET['perPage'])){
    $perPage=$_GET['perPage'];
}
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    $url=$_GET['url'];
}

$qrystring = '';

if(isset($facets) && strlen($facets) > 0){
    $qrystring .= '?facets=' . urlencode($facets);
}elseif(isset($id) && strlen($id) >0) {
    $qrystring .= '?id=' . urlencode($id);
}else{
    echo 'Parameter missing';
    exit;
}
if(isset($sortBy) && strlen($sortBy) > 0){
    $qrystring .= '&sortBy=' . urlencode($sortBy);
}
if(isset($perPage) && strlen($perPage) > 0){
    $qrystring .= '&perPage=' . urlencode($perPage);
}
if(isset($url) && strlen($url) > 0){
    $path = $url;
}

/**
 * Step 1: Get a Request token
 */
$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
$oauth->enableDebug();
$oauth->setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM); // switch to POST request
$request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url);

// Display error if there's been a problem fetching the request token.
if(empty($request_token_info)) {
    print "Failed fetching request token, response was: " . $oauth->getLastResponse();
    exit();
}

/**
 * Step 2: Set Request Token to log in
 */
$oauth->setToken($request_token_info['oauth_token'],$request_token_info['oauth_token_secret']);

/**
 * Step 3: Use request token to log in and authenticate for 3-legged auth. The response (via callback URL in $req_url) contains the OAuth token and verifier
 */
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
$submit = "Login";
$url = $auth_submiturl;

// Using cURL generate and make the call to the Beatport API
$curl_connection_bp = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11");
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false); // when true, this outputs the oauth_token and oauth_verifier value that are posted to the callback URL
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_REFERER, $curl_connection_bp);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
$post_string = 'oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token'] . '&username=' . $beatport_login . '&password=' . $beatport_password . '&submit=Login';
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$beatport_response = curl_exec($curl_connection_bp);
$beatport_response = json_decode($beatport_response);

/**
 * Step 4: Use verifier string to request the Access Token
 */
$get_access_token = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_url, "", $beatport_response->oauth_verifier);
if(empty($get_access_token)) {
    print "Failed fetching access token, response was: " . $oauth->getLastResponse();
    exit();
}

/**
 * Step 5: Set Access Token for further requests
 */
$oauth->setToken($get_access_token['oauth_token'],$get_access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

/**
 * Step 6: Test request.
 */
$oauth->fetch('https://oauth-api.beatport.com/catalog/3/' . $path . $qrystring);
$json = $oauth->getLastResponse();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $json;

?>
```

It's taken from a developer on GitHub. I'm no pro at coding, so I am not sure if it's my code that's creating the problem, or if it's because the OAuth PHP extension is not installed on my server even though it should be. What is the mistake in my code, or is the OAuth PHP extension not installed on my server?

Comment: The `OAuth` class is part of `PECL OAuth >= 0.99.1`, so it's a PECL module. http://php.net/OAuth

Comment: so PECL OAuth needs installing on my server?

Comment: Yes, OAuth is not part of any current PHP cores.

Comment: mmm funny because my hosting provider keeps saying that it is for some reason. thanks for the response

Comment: Then he should take a peek at the PHP manual page. It clearly says it's a PECL module.

Answer (score -1):

OAuth PHP isn't part of the core php, you'll need to install it via `PECL`, here's how:

First try: `yum install php-pecl-oauth` and restart apache

---

If the above doesn't work, try the following:

**Installing OAuth for PHP clients on CentOS 6**

1. Installing `EPEL` and `Remi` repo on CentOS 6

---

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

2. `sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`
   **set** : `enabled=1` on the topmost repo

---

3. `yum install php-pecl-oauth`

---

4. Restart apache

---

SRC: http://www.ontwerps.nl/installing-oauth-php-clients-centos-6

Comment: How to install oAuth in localhost wamp windows os.

Comment: I'd create a new question for that, probably on https://serverfault.com/